# GWT RequestFactory + Validation Groups

Tags: java, validation, gwt, bean-validation, requestfactory

Is there a way to use validation groups with request factory. If I execute a request all annotations are checked. But sometimes I want to validate only a part of the constraints. Is this possible with GWT request factory version 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a custom `ServiceLayerDecorator` to `RequestFactoryServlet` and override `ServiceLayerDecorator.validate(T domain)` so as you can use your customised groups.